# Can we force the Postback on click of a submit button (MVC3)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I ve a Form, which has two submit buttons (One in the main form & other one in a hidden div, which is visible in certain scenarios).

In the 1st scenario, the submit button is working fine, but when the div is displayed as a pop up window, upon clicking the submit button in the div, no action is fired.

But I want the form to be submitted to the controller, as the div is also a part of the parent Form.
***My intention behind this is to initiate Model Binding & to collect all the Form element values in my controller.***

Can I force the Form post using Jquery & initiate Model Binding upon the 2nd submit button click ?
My Form looks Something like :

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectSuggestedAddress", "Dispatch", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))
        { ....

     <p>
         <input id= "btn1" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```

& in the div I have some controls with another submit button :

```
<div style="display: none">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
    <p>
         <input id= "btn2" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="InitiatePost()" />
    </p>
    }
<div>
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
function InitiatePost() {
    alert("Posting the Form");
    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        $('#myform').submit();
    });
```

***Should it initiate the post & do Model Binding & to collect all the Form element values in my controller.***

In my case the alert is firing on button click, but POST is not happening. 
Please help me in rectifying my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {    
        $('#btn2').click(function() {
            $('#btn1').trigger('click');
        });
    });
```

Comment: alert( $('#myform').valid()+ ' '+  $('#myform').length); what value it is returning? on button click btn2